# Google Play Store: Refund a user through order management, block the autorenewal?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, in-app-subscription

I have some users of one of my app that activated auto-renewal on one subscription.

The subscription plan since one week is now disabled and no longer visible/selectable from the app but these users with auto-renewal active, they are still able to renew it and use the no more valid subscription.

I want to refund them and stop them to renew..
There is an action in Order Management in play store console to refund but..

[image]

I'm searching in the docs.. and I didn't find nothing mentioning if this action will remove automatic renewal.
The only thing I found is this api call
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/revoke?hl=it but ..
I don't want to implement automatic refund mechanism, we are talking about less than 20 users... I can handle manually..
does this refund DISABLE the automatic renewal?

Answer (score 1):

When you click that refund button, it'll take you to [another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZr6S.png) where you can specify the percent to be refunded, whether the user should still have entitlement to the subscription for the remainder of the term, etc. You can check that "remove entitlement" box to stop a user's subscription.

If that's not there, make sure you're refunding the most-recent renewal.